# Counting entries of subdocument in MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document structure like so

```
{
    "_id" : "3:/content/somepath/test.txt",
    "_revisions" : {
        "r152f47f1daf-0-2" : "c",
        "r152f48413c1-0-2" : "c",
        "r152f4851bf7-0-1" : "c"
    }
}
```

My task is to find all documents with the following conditions:

- The "_id" needs to start with "5:"
- The number of revisions need to be exclusively greater then 3

The first part is easy, I have solved it with

```
db.nodes.find( {'_id': /^5:/} )
```

But I am struggling with the second part, am supposed to use `$gt`.

Since I am new to MongoDB, I was first looking at `$size`, but `_revisions` is not an array, it is a subdocument, right?.

Was also looking at `$unwind` and then counting the results, but that does not make sense either, since my result need to be the documents that match the above two conditions.

Any pointers highly appreciated.

Comment: A better design would be to make your `_revisions` field an array of sub-documents. something like, `"_revisions":[{"key":"r...","value":"c"}]`. The key is to design your schema in such a way that 90% of the queries that you fire can easily fetch the results without complex client or server side logic being involved. Moreover, It is a better design to have key names as `predefined attributes` and **not** dynamic/hashed strings.

Comment: @BatScream that is what I mentioned in my answer but OP seems to want to use the `$gt` operator without changing their documents structure which is not possible here.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator.

```js
db.nodes.find(function() { 
    return (/^5:/.test(this._id) && Object.keys(this._revisions).length > 3 ); 
})
```

The problem with this as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations) is that:

> `$where` evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., `$gt`, `$in`).

You should definitely consider to change the `_revisions` field to an array of sub-documents like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : "3:/content/somepath/test.txt",
    "_revisions" : [
        { 
            "rev": "r152f47f1daf-0-2",
            "value": "c"
        },
        {   
            "rev": "r152f48413c1-0-2",
            "value": "c"
        },
        {    
            "rev": "r152f4851bf7-0-1",
            "value": "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

And use the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator.

```js
db.nodes.find({ "_id": /^5:/, "_revisions.3": { "$exists": true } } )
```

Comment: Actually, I can not change the _revisions field. The task is part of a curriculum. I would have preferred that as well and also looked at the $exists operator. But they want us to use the $gt operator, that does not make sense to me, since _revisions is not an array.